# Command lvcreate throwing an invalid flag error?

Tags: linux, lxc, lvm, lxd

I'm working on a group project that involves having to use the command lvcreate. When trying to run lvcreate with certain flags, this error message appears (the flags passed in are in the error message):

```
Error: Error Creating LVM LV for new image: Could not create thin LV named custom_vol0: Failed to run: lvcreate -i 2 -I 64K -Wy --yes --thin -n custom_vol0 --virtualsize 10GB poolA/LXDThinPool: Command does not accept option: --stripes 2.
  Command does not accept option: --stripesize 64K
```

This is the info of the storage pool we are trying to create custom_vol0 on

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               poolA
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <27.94 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7152
  Alloc PE / Size       7152 / <27.94 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               zJfbN1-0x7E-gteT-r0SV-Grh4-ewtc-fikl38
```

Can a thinly provisioned logical volume have a greater number of stripes than the number of physical volumes in the volume group? Is the mix of flags above an issue? The error message is not very descriptive.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: You will need second PV to make number of stripes 2